# How to return preliminary undefined struct from a function in C?

Tags: c, function, struct, return

A small snippet is shown below:

```
struct module SELECT(FILE *f, int id, int db) {
    if (id == 1) {
        module table;
        return table;
    } else if (id == 2) {
        level table;
        return table;
    }
}
```

How can I make the function to return either `module` or `level` structure depends on the function processing?

Here are my `module` and `level` structures:

```
typedef struct module {
    int id;
    char name[30];
    int mem_num;
    int cell_num;
    int del;
} module;

typedef struct level {
    int mem_num;
    int cell_count;
    int def;
} level;
```

Example of call:

IK that str connects with level structure (e.g.).

```
FILE *tmp = fopen(str, "r");
level res = SELECT(tmp, 1, 1);
```

Comment: `SELECT` is declared as returning a `module`, but you're returning a `level` in line 7 of `SELECT`. What do you expect?

Comment: You can't. A function has one return type. Make two functions.

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: @Jabberwocky just as example. Idk what to pass instead of it, it's actually the described issue.

Comment: How do you intend to call `SELECT`? [Edit]  and show an example.

Comment: You could pass in pointers to both `module` and `level`, then return a flag to say which one you set, but as @Jabberwocky says, you probably have an XY Problem.

Comment: The clean and straigtforward solution for this situation is to write two different functions. Anything else is making it more complicated than necessary. Keep it simple.

Comment: Can't be done. If you really, really need it, a work around could be a tagged union.

Answer (score 2):

*How can I make the function to return either module or level structure depends on the function processing?*

You can't do this, and in this stituation should't shouldn't even try. Well that's not entirely true, you could use void pointers and weird casts or use other weird methods, but there is no benefit in this situation.

Just have two different functions and call them as needed:

```
module SELECT_MODULE(FILE *f, int db) {
    module table;
    ...
    return table;
}

level SELECT_LEVEL(FILE *f, int db) {
    level table;
    ...
    return table;
}
```

---

```
FILE *tmp = fopen(str, "r");
...
level res = SELECT_LEVEL(tmp, 1);

...
module mod = SELECT_MODULE(tmp, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `union`.

```
module_or_level SELECT(FILE *f, int id, int db) {
    if (id == 1) {
        module_or_level table = {.type = t_module, .m = ... };
        return table;
    } else if (id == 2) {
        module_or_level table = {.type = t_level, .l = ... };
        return table;
    }
}

typedef struct module {
    int id;
    char name[30];
    int mem_num;
    int cell_num;
    int del;
} module;

typedef struct level {
    int mem_num;
    int cell_count;
    int def;
} level;

enum module_or_level_type {
  t_level,
  t_module
};

typedef struct {
  enum module_or_level_type type;
  union {
    module m;
    level l;
  };
} module_or_level;
```

calling:

```
FILE *tmp = fopen(str, "r");
module_or_level res = SELECT(tmp, 1, 1);
switch(res.type) {
case t_module: do_something_with(res.m); break;
case t_level: do_something_with(res.l); break;
}
```